# VS Code - the type or namespace name 'System' could not be found error

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am learning VS Code with .Net Core.

I have installed `.Net Core 3.0 SDK`.

I have also installed the following extensions in VS Code

- C# ms-vscode.csharp C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp).
- .NET Core Starter's Pack blairleduc.net-core-starters-pack
- C# FixFormat leopotam.csharpfixformat

As you can see in the following image, vs code is showing errors on almost all key words. How can i fix this?

[image]

I can do `dotnet run` without any issue and `Hellow World!` displays for me.

I have added following to settings.json file by following this https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/928

```
"csharp.suppressDotnetRestoreNotification": true
```

I have also added the following to the csproj file

```
<NoWarn>8019</NoWarn>
```

I have also performed `dotnet restore` and also performed any suggestions put in front by VS Code. Still no luck fixing this issue.

VS Code version info

```
Version: 1.39.1 (user setup)
Commit: 88f15d17dca836346e787762685a40bb5cce75a8
Date: 2019-10-10T23:31:28.683Z
Electron: 4.2.10
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17763
```

Comment: Did you fix it?